# Disposing a singleton instance shared between NUnit tests

Tags: c#, redis, nunit, stackexchange.redis, nunit-3.0

I have a bunch of NUnit acceptance tests (that is, not *unit* tests) that need to connect to several Redis instances during the course of the execution.

StackExchange.Redis best practices advise to store and reuse the ConnectionMultiplexer instances (see here: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Basics), so I came up with this singleton that allows to re-use a ConnectionMultiplexer object:

```
internal static class RedisConnectionCache
{
    // concurrency locks omitted for simplicity
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, IConnectionMultiplexer> ConnectionCache = new Dictionary<string, IConnectionMultiplexer>();
    public static IConnectionMultiplexer GetMultiplexer(string connectionString)
    {
        if (ConnectionCache.TryGetValue(connectionString, out var multiplexer))
        {
            return multiplexer;
        }

        var multiplexer= ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(ConfigurationOptions.Parse(connectionString));
        ConnectionCache.Add(connectionString, multiplexer);

        return multiplexer;
    }
}
```

Which is then invoked like this in many tests:

```
var redisConnection = RedisConnectionCache.GetMultiplexer(connectionString);
var redisDb = redisConnection.GetDatabase(db);
redisDb.KeyDelete(key);
```

Unfortunately, since this is all happening inside many different NUnit test fixtures, I don't have a good way to dispose my dictionary of Redis connections.

Provided that I need to reuse the connection objects between different test fixtures inside the same test run, what are my options? 
So far, the best I can think of is `OneTimeTearDown` test that would empty the connections after all tests are done.

Comment: Yes that would be the way to go.Before each `TestFixture` you could set the `Dictionary` in the `OneTimeSetUp` method and destroy it in the `TearDown`.One other option would be to have a single `TestFixture` class and use it as a partial class.You would then separate your `TestFixtures` only by filename.

Comment: Take a look at Nunit's Setup Fixtures. That will allow you to do a teardown after either a whole namespaces worth of tests, or a whole assembly's worth.

Comment: @Chris thank you! I've implemented your suggestion and it works like a charm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup Fixture does the trick here. One caveat is that I needed to put the class **outside of the test namespaces** to run after any tests in the assembly.

In a generic fashion, my code ended up being similar to this:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
// ReSharper disable CheckNamespace

[SetUpFixture]
public class SingletonTeardown
{
    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void RunAfter()
    {
        if (SingletonType.Instance.IsValueCreated)
        {
            SingletonType.Instance.Value.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```